# Help identifying American Standard cartridge

Tags: plumbing-fixture, cartridge, american-standard

Loosing hot water pressure, going to change the cartridge out but I am having a hard time finding the correct replacement. Pictures are attached.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could take the cartridge to a pluming supply store. We do not have enough info to figure it out from here.

Comment: what do you get if you google `american standard 1495`?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. This really isn't a good fit for here, especially as you can get the info you need yourself. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.